# create array of strings, then check occurrence of those strings in cells

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary, find

I have a very long list of company names in a column A as strings. They contain “LLC”, “llc”, “limited”, “Ltd.” etc in all combinations. I need to create a list (dictionary) and check for the incidence of any of these combinations in the cell string, then output a Boolean yes/no to the adjacent cell in Column B if any of the dictionary entry is present in the name.

Couldn’t create a dynamic array with a python type list.append command.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Without VBA or python you can use this:

```
=SUM(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:$E$3,A1)))
```

`SEARCH` to check if any of the strings are contained in the company name

`--` and `ISNUMBER` to convert matches and non-matches to 1 and 0

`SUM` to combine the matches into a single result.

You could also add a `=1` at the end to convert to `TRUE` / `FALSE`

[image]